# "Package orca has no installation candidate"

Tags: ubuntu, orca

This error occur when trying to install orca using `apt-get install orca`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gnome-orca` is the package name.

```
$ dpkg -l '*orca*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Cfg-files/Unpacked/Failed-cfg/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                Version             Description
+++-===================-===================-===========================
un  gnome-orca          <none>              (no description available)
un  gnome-orca-common   <none>              (no description available)
```